# Add lines on ImageView IOS (objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

I need some help to get this thing working..

Basically on button click, I have to add a line of fixed width with circle end points on the ImageView. User can add upto 5 lines. If I click on any circle (red dot) end point of line, it should allow to resize the line. Point can be dragged to any position on screen and line has to be straight. At the end, i should be able to calculate the length of each line. I just spent a lot of time on this and referring other similar answers. But so far, no luck.. Any reference code or links is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: This is the `viewDidLoad` function, it will be called at the beginning, but not again.  So it is working.  What is the code with your `handleOnTap` type of function?

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't understand how to proceed further.. Because i have to add objects on ImageView, user can add upto 10 lines. My first doubt is,, what should i use to display LINE, a UiView or UiImage.... This is what i have done so far .. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the first place I would start.  Try some tutorials on handling button clicks and user screen interaction and modify them to do this, or come back to this later.

Comment: you got me wrong, i have published two IOS apps,, but my point was i recently started with core graphics ;-) I was thinking, if i add 10 UiViews (lines) on UiImageView then will it have impact on memory...so needed some ideas to accomplish this efficiently..

Comment: You dont need the (objective-c) in your question, let the `tags` do their work..

Answer (score 2):

WOW, where to even start. OK, first of all, you should not be doing your drawing in the "viewDidLoad" method of your ViewController. You should make a subclass of UIView (let's call it DrawView) and do all your drawing within the "drawRect" method. And within DrawView, you can then intercept touches.

So to get a little more precise:

1. create subclass of UIView called DrawView
2. Move your drawing into the drawRect method
3. Within DrawView, over-ride the various "touchesXXXX" methods (of UIResponder) to detect and respond to touches and figure out what shape has been touched
4. Within the storyboard, drag a UIView object onto your ViewController and make sure it's class is set to "DrawView".

This is for starters. Haven't even talked about how to record/store your various points and shapes.

Comment: Appreciate your help for description.. Can also give me some links so i can refer/learn and do it. Basically i have just started a month ago.. can't just solve without seeing code.. Thanks

Comment: Sure, Ray Wenderlich's site is excellent... here's one but definitely go and check out other tutorials on his site:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-in-ios-5-a-5-star-rating-view

Answer (score 1):

To Draw line on image view the following code work for me even in view did load.

**first** int image view

**second** write following code

```
//line 1
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayerOne = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayerOne.path = [LineOne CGPath];
shapeLayerOne.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
shapeLayerOne.lineWidth = 1.0;
shapeLayerOne.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];

//line 2

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayerTwo = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayerTwo.path = [LineTwo CGPath];
shapeLayerTwo.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
shapeLayerTwo.lineWidth = 1.0;
shapeLayerTwo.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];


//line 3

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayerThree = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayerThree.path = [LineThree CGPath];
shapeLayerThree.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
shapeLayerThree.lineWidth = 1.0;
shapeLayerThree.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];


//line 4

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayerFour = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayerFour.path = [LineFour CGPath];
shapeLayerFour.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
shapeLayerFour.lineWidth = 1.0;
shapeLayerFour.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];


[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayerOne];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayerTwo];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayerThree];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayerFour];
```

**your output is blue line**

Comment: wow,,, how can i make them moveable by touching red points,, any ideas

Comment: simple solution is that u can init your line with image view  and use pinch gesture